# Is it possible to set up a raspberry pi with an Active Directory account?

Tags: linux, active-directory, raspberry-pi

We are looking at various ways of giving our raspberry pis access to our network and I was wondering if it was possible to give a Pi an active directory account so it can log on to a windows network?

Comment: Which Operating System are you running on the device? Raspbian? In general: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Yes sorry, it is raspbian